# How to scroll ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have ExpandableListView that contains groupviews and childviews. I set ExpandableListView height to some extent, but it is not scrolling at all. Why it happends?

I put it in ScrollView also, but no use..

Plz any one can help me..?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="460dp"
android:background="@drawable/dealer_contact_body_bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/header_bg" >
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/load_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/il_header_bg" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pick_insp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pick_insp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tripnumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/trip_no"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/driver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/driver"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/date"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/pir_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ir_vin_header_bg" >
</TableRow>

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:clickable="true" >
</ExpandableListView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signature_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/signature_btn" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toggle_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/toggle_row"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:background="@drawable/il_header_bg" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="990dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_menu"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />
    </TableRow>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/navbar_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_trip"
            style="@style/navbar_button"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_trip"
            android:text="@string/trip" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSep1"
            android:layout_width="3dp"
            android:layout_x="253dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_separation" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_inspection"
            style="@style/navbar_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_inspection"
            android:text="@string/insp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSep2"
            android:layout_width="3dp"
            android:layout_x="509dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_separation" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_edvir"
            style="@style/navbar_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_edvir"
            android:text="@string/edvir" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSep3"
            android:layout_width="3dp"
            android:layout_x="765dp"
            android:background="@drawable/menu_separation" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_account"
            style="@style/navbar_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_account"
            android:text="@string/account" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please anyone help me..?

Comment: Post your layout code so that you can know what you have done wrong....

Comment: Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to put it in scroll view.
ExpandableView by default has scroll View.

You might be making some mistake in height of the expandable view or the parent height.
Here is how the expandable list may look for a fixed height of 250.

```
 <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandable_list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dip"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </ExpandableListView>
```

Also, Read about Expandable View: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

***Note: You cannot use the value wrap_content for the android:layout_height attribute of a ExpandableListView in XML if the parent's size is also not strictly specified (for example, if the parent were ScrollView you could not specify wrap_content since it also can be any length. However, you can use wrap_content if the ExpandableListView parent has a specific size, such as 100 pixels.***

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I will try with that solution

Answer (score 0):

Use this code inside adapter

```
@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    
    expandableListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(final AbsListView view, final int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                view.setOnScrollListener(null);

                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        view.setSelection(pos);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, final int firstVisibleItem, final int visibleItemCount,
                             final int totalItemCount) {
        }
    });
}
```

'pos' takes value of childview position